# Drawing a "pointer triangle" in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIStackView consisting of clickable images. Whenever I tap one of them, a UIView appears on the right side of the stack, showing some more info about the clicked object. I'm trying to make a triangle, that will show user to what line in the stack does the UIView relate to, like shown in the picture:

[image]

I don't know how to do that though. My solution would be probably just make 10 UIImageViews (there's 10 lines in the stack) and whenever user taps an image,set it's corresponding UIImageView to a triangle and the rest to nil. That's clunky and dirty, though, is there any better solution? I'm sure there lots of ways to accomplish that, but what's the best one?

Comment: I would suggest doing it with  `CALayer` / `CAShapeLayer`
Make a layer (that is drawing a triangle and position it accordingly)
Actually same (but worse performant) can be done with only 1 `UIImage`
Just position it at needed coordinate

Comment: Ah, seems like I really need to finish reading through the Ray's tutorial about CG now.

Comment: Yes he has a great tutorial about `CALayer`s I think there is also an example in drawing triangles - well not a triangle but he has some polygons there I suggest to start from learning it.

Comment: Why is it a stack view with another view beside? Why not a table view with configurable cells?

Comment: @Wain The stack has static content (10 images). The content of the right UIView depends on the image tapped (one view for every image, 9 lines of text per view, 90 lines total). You can imagine the stack working as a filter of sorts, showing just the information you want.